# Weird mouse issue with OS X 10.7.4 on 21" iMac

Tags: macos, imac, mouse

I'm having some strange problems with my year-old iMac running OS X 10.7.4.
After clicking on a menu item on the top menu bar, the drop down menu that appears disappears instantly. This also happens when right clicking on the desktop or on an application in the dock. It's as if single clicks are getting counted as double clicks.

Sometimes, the cursor just disappears. It reappears when moving the mouse, but keeps flickering.

It's not a problem with my Apple wireless mouse. I also tried a wired Logitech mouse and had the same problem; so, it must be a software bug, not a hardware problem.

I started experiencing the issue after doing a software update to OS X 10.7.4, but I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem.

I have uploaded a video of the problem here: http://tinypic.com/r/2vxk9af/6

Comment: I remember this happening to me. If I recall correctly, some Application was requesting the focus of the mouse. Try rebooting in [safe mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564) and tell us if it keeps happening.

Comment: What kind of keyboard are you using, check the keyboard, it may be causing random input  when your not expecting it to and maybe causing the mouse cursor to flicker, since key input cause the cursor to hide while typing on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I've occasionally had problems over the years with weird mouse issues, and bar once, they were all fixed by deleting the "com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse" file located in ~user\Library\Preferences. Upon reboot the file will be recreated, and you can bak it up first in case it changes something. Software updates can sometimes change/corrupt plist files, and deleting them to fix issues is fairly common.

Worth a try if you're struggling for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I have also been suffering this odd double-click issue for several months.

I think I finally figured out the problem for me.

It's iTunes.

If I have iTunes running I get odd double-clicks when trying to select files in Finder. With iTunes off I don't get these.

Comment: Very interesting. Have you been able to isolate it further? Is music playing or iTunes Match downloading / streaming? Also, does iTunes show a substantial load in Activity Monitor for CPU when the clicks are being lost / delayed?